# 2d runner same spacing between different sized gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my problem is keeping same spacing between different sized prefabs in randomly generated 2d runner.
 i want to spawn new gameobject every second
let's say i have simple  sprite called square 
i am spawning it using coroutine and distance is  always equal to 1s of movement
i added different sized arrays of squares as prefab and when i spawn it with 1 unit squares i would love to have same distance between prefabs as if i was spawning single squares one after another.
basically i would love to spawn different sized prefabs and spawn them at same interval by keeping same distance between different prefabs.
maybe the solution is to spawn prefabs based on  measured distance between prefabs instead of spawning based on time
how would you aproach this problem?
can i calculate width of empty gameObject based on width of array of its children?
i hope you can understand what  am i asking
thank you!

```
 void Start() {
    stvaranjeFunkc();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {



        if (privremeniNiz.tag == "zamka")
        {
            if (privremeniNiz.transform.position.x + privremeniNiz.transform.localScale.x / 2 < stvarac.transform.position.x - vrijednostGranice)
                stvaranjeFunkc();
        }

        if (privremeniNiz.tag == "nizPreprekaZamka")
        {

        // if ((privremeniNiz.GetComponent<nizKutija>().niz[privremeniNiz.GetComponent<nizKutija>().randomBrKutija].transform.position.x + privremeniNiz.GetComponent<nizKutija>().niz[privremeniNiz.GetComponent<nizKutija>().randomBrKutija].transform.localScale.x / 2)
        //> stvarac.transform.position.x - vrijednostGranice)
         if ((privremeniNiz.gameObject.GetComponent<nizKutija>().niz[0].transform.position.x + privremeniNiz.GetComponent<nizKutija>().niz[0].transform.localScale.x / 2)
        > stvarac.transform.position.x - vrijednostGranice)
        return;


       // if (privremeniNiz.GetComponent<nizKutija>().niz[privremeniNiz.GetComponent<nizKutija>().randomBrKutija].transform.position.x + privremeniNiz.GetComponent<nizKutija>().niz[privremeniNiz.GetComponent<nizKutija>().randomBrKutija].transform.localScale.x / 2 < stvarac.transform.position.x - vrijednostGranice)
            stvaranjeFunkc();
        }

    //if (!cekanje)
    //    StartCoroutine(stvaranje());
    //else return;
}

void stvaranjeFunkc()
{
    int poz = Random.Range(0, prepreka.Length);
    GameObject temp =Instantiate(prepreka[poz], stvarac.transform.position, stvarac.transform.rotation);
    privremeniNiz = temp;
}
```

i got it working when i have simple gameobject (tag=zamka) but when  i
spawn gameobject of tag nizPreprekaZamka  which is empty gameobject that has script attached which creates array of simple objects spawner just spawns hundreds of gameobjects at once

Comment: Please post [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt before posting.

Comment: This question should be moved to game development SE

Answer (score 0):

You probably know the speed that your game horizontally scrolls. I'm assuming you're tracking the position of each block and you can tell what their widths are.

The trick is to spawn the blocks off-screen so you always have enough content to scroll into view to cover the next frame.

How much content is off-screen? I'm assuming you just append new blocks to the end of the array. That means the last block is always the furthest off-screen, which helps us. It also helps to know the size of the screen. In that case, you can calculate the amount of content off-screen as `last block position + its length + fixed_space - screen size`, where `fixed_space` is the amount of space you want after each block.

Check each frame if the scroll speed > the amount of content off-screen. If so, you need to generate a new block. Your block's starting position should be exactly where the content off-screen ended.

Comment: Nope, the concepts I've illustrated should help you come to a conclusion about how to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

The position of a `GameObject` is located at its center, while is scale is his total size.

So the edge of an object is located at its position plus half the scale:

`float distance = transform.position.x + (transform.scale.x / 2f);`

So for each new prefab, you want to add the distance between the center and edge of both GameObject plus the distance that should seperate them.

```
public GameObject[] prefabs;
public float distanceBetweenObjects;

float newPosition = prefabs[0].transform.position.x;

newPosition += (prefabs[0].transform.scale.x / 2f);
newPosition += distanceBetweenObjects;
newPosition += (prefabs[1].transform.scale.x / 2f);
```